# T/F: $\exists x\in(0,1] \forall y\in(0,1](x \leq y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question 1: T/F:
$\exists x\in(0,1] \forall y\in(0,1](x \leq y)$

My first assumption is this statement is true. However, I'm having trouble providing a sufficient proof since we cannot find the 'smallest number' next to 0.

Comment: Another way to read the statement is "does there exist some element $x$ in (0,1] such that for all y in (0,1] $x \leq y?$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, the question is, "does the interval $(0,1]$ have a smallest element?
". If $a\in(0,1]$ then surely $a/2\in(0,1]$ also?

Comment: Wow, it makes a lot more sense now, thanks!